# Is a subdirectory of /tmp a suitable place for Unix sockets?

Tags: permissions, security, tmp, unix-sockets

I am looking for a secure place to put Unix domain sockets that will be used to control a REPL.

On Linux, I would use `/run/user/$UID`, which meets all requirements except for portability.  I need the program that handles them to be portable.

One option is to use a directory under `~` but that runs into a different problem: the user's home directory might be in a directory too deep to be able to bind a Unix domain socket to, due to the limit in the path length.

Placing the socket in a directory under `/tmp` is portable, but I am worried about race conditions upon removing the directory.  I am also worried about whether `/tmp` can be relied on to have the sticky bit set on all platforms (that is, for users to not be able to delete or rename other user's temporary files).  I am assuming that `/tmp` IS sticky, however, as otherwise many, many applications (every script that uses `mkstemp`) is insecure.

My current plan is for the server to create a temporary directory in `/tmp`, and for the clients to check the ownership of the containing directory before using the socket.  Is this adequate for security?

Comment: By-the-way note: On Linux, you could also use a path whose first byte is a null byte. This is a special Linux kernel convention for AF_UNIX socket addresses which are in a space that has no file system mapping.

Comment: Speaking of permissions, not all Unix-like OS's honor the file system permissions on sockets. (LInux does.)  You can't portably rely on the fact that "if the client connected to this socket, it is authenticated and authorized because of the perms on the socket itself".

Comment: @Kaz my idea is to put the socket in a secure directory, and use the permissions on the directory.

Comment: @thrig in what way?

Comment: From Perl module smoke test reports, folks do (if rarely) screw up their `/tmp` directory permissions. Details vary, though I've seen 0700 mode permissions or other wacky changes from the default. So you'll need lots of error checking (and to yell at the user or otherwise log the problem) and shouldn't assume anything about `/tmp` working.

Comment: @thrig A broken `/tmp` is a system misconfiguration. This is not something that an application needs to concern itself with. An application should check if `TMPDIR` is set, however. If `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` is not writable, just print an error message and give up.

Comment: @Gilles printing an error message after a check is a fine example of an application concerning itself with a misconfiguration. But you also said this not something an application needs to concern itself with?? O_o

Comment: @thrig Pretty much any OS interaction can fail, e.g. read or write error because the disk has failed or the network is down, a memory allocation fails because there isn't any free memory, etc. A lot of software development is about coping with errors. An application does not need to concern itself with this misconfiguration, i.e. it doesn't need to have any fallback behavior if that fails, any more than if creating the temporary file fails because the disk is out of space. Of course it needs to treat it as an error, but it doesn't need specific handling for this misconfiguration.

Answer (score 4):

The [*de jure* standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) location for temporary files is given in the environment variable `TMPDIR`.

> This variable shall represent a pathname of a directory made available for programs that need a place to create temporary files.

In fact, many systems do not define `TMPDIR`. The *de facto* standard location for temporary files is `/tmp`. So check `TMPDIR`, and if it is not set, use `/tmp`. In a shell script, you can use `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}`, or if you find it more convenient,

```
if [ -z "$TMPDIR" ]; then TMPDIR=/tmp; fi
```

or to cope with `set -u`

```
: "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}"
```

You can assume that this location is writable, but it may be world-readable and world-writable, so:

- When you create a regular file, always make sure that you aren't overwriting an existing file, which might not belong to you. Don't use a shell redirection for this. It is not safe to test ownership separately because an adversary may move symbolic links around while your program is running to fool the checks. Additionally you can't rely on a particular name not existing; to prevent a concurrent program from creating a denial of service by creating a file with the same name just before you, use a random name. You can use the `mktemp` utility (widespread, present on GNU, BusyBox, BSD, but not POSIX) or the `mkstemp` C library function. Under the hood, `open` or `creat` must be called with the `O_EXCL` flag.
- You can create a directory with `mkdir`. This is secure against ownership trickery stealing, because that won't reuse an existing file, but it is prone to the same denial of service as regular files, so you should use a random name. `mktemp -d` is a fine way to do this.
- You can create a socket (there's no standard shell utility for that). Like the directory case, it is secure against ownership trickery but not against denial of service.
  Linux honors permissions on named sockets, but there are Unix variants that don't. This is why sockets in `/tmp` are usually created in subdirectories.

Programs that create a subdirectory of `/tmp` (or `$TMPDIR` if set) and create a named socket there include X11 servers, ssh-agent, gpg-agent, KDE, emacs, … (that's just the ones that exist on the machine where I'm posting this). As you can see, you'll be in good company.

Comment: If `ssh-agent` and `gpg-agent` (both of which can be assumed to be by people who know what they are doing regarding security), then I am not too worried.  I guess I can assume that some other user can't do `mv /tmp/my_directory /tmp/some_other_directory`?

Comment: @Demi Another user can't remove or rename your files, due to the sticky bit on the directory.